Spring boot Java REST API calling via Javascript - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
I have successfully created few REST APIs with Spring boot which are working fine on postman and Visual Code extension Thunder Client.
But when I try to call APIs from HTML via JavaScript is throws errors.

Here is the HTML code
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crickinfo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>APIs</h1>
        <button onclick="greeting()">Greeting</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function greeting()
    {
        let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open("GET", 'http://localhost:8080/player/greeting');
        httpRequest.send();
        httpRequest.onload = function(){
            alert(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
        console.log("inside the html file");
    }
</script>
</html>

I have spent a lot of for proper solution but no luck.
I also read No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API
but here no proper implementation shared.

Did you add the cors method to your httpsecurity? or have you used the @CrossOrigin annotation in your controllers?
